# Dense Subsets Of Topological Subspaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Suppose that $(X, T)$ be a topological space and $A$ be an arbitrary non empty subset of $X$, then $A$ is dense in the subspace $(\bar A, T')$, where $T'$ is the relative topology.
$$$$I want to verify my proof. Please tell me about any mistakes or any corrections (minor or major) is required??Thank You
$$$$To prove that above statement we just have to prove that $$\bar{A'}=\bar A$$, where $\bar{A'}$ is the new closure of $A$ under the topology $T'$. It is easy to see that $$\bar{A'} \subset \bar A$$, so we just have to prove that $$\bar A \subset \bar{A'}$$. Suppose this is not true then there is a $x \in \bar A$ such that $x$ does not lie in $\bar{A'}$. So there exists a set $D$ such that $$A \subset D \subset \bar A$$ and $D^c \in T'$ and $x$ does not lie in $D$. Now as $D^c \in T'$, so $$D^c = \bar A \cap P$$ for some $P \in T$, by the definition of relative topology. Now as $x$ is not in $D$, so $x \in D^c$. So $x \in P$, also as $P \in T$ so $P^c$ is closed under the topology $T$. Also it is easy to see that $D^c \subset P$ and hence $P^c \subset D$. Now as for any $y \in A$ we have $$y \in D \subset \bar A$$, and hence $y$ does not lie in $D^c$, and hence $y$ does not lie in $P$ and hence $y \in P^c$. So we have $A \subset P^c$ and hence we have $$A \subset P^c \subset D \subset \bar A$$. Now as $x \in \bar A$, so by the definition $x$ lies in every superset of $A$ which is closed under $T$ but as $x$ is not in $P^c$ which is a superset of $A$ and closed under $T$, so a contradiction. And hence $$\bar A \subset \bar{A'}$$. And hence $A$ is a dense subset of the topological space $(\bar A, T')$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Your proof is correct, but it’s more complicated than necessary. Let $x\in\cl_TA$, and suppose that $x\in U\in T'$. By the definition of $T'$ there is a $V\in T$ such that $U=V\cap\cl_TA$, so $x\in V$. $V$ is an open nbhd of $x$ in $X$, and $x\in\cl_TA$, so $V\cap A\ne\varnothing$, and therefore $U\cap A=V\cap(\cl_TA)\cap A=V\cap A\ne\varnothing$. Thus, every $T'$-open nbhd of $x$ intersects $A$, so $x\in\cl_{T'}A$. This shows that $\cl_TA\subseteq\cl_{T'}A$, and as you say, it’s easy to see that $\cl_{T'}A\subseteq\cl_TA$.